# Flutter test finder can't find widgets after tap

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, gui-testing, textformfield

## The Problem

I have 3 textfields with the suffix icon widget of each being a row of 2 FloatingActionButtons. One icon clears the textfield, and the other validates it.

[The widget layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlaP6.png)

The finder I use in my unit tests (`find.byIcon(Icons.done_rounded)`) will initially find 3 widgets, as expected. Then after tapping the first widget (`await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.done_rounded).at(0));`) the subsequent taps for the remaining 2 fail to find the widgets (PumpAndSettle is called after each tap).

Not only are the remaining buttons not able to be found, but any other widget, including ones with keys, aren't able to be found.

Running the test on the simulator and calling idle after the first tap shows this.

[The widget layout after tapping the first button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhRq8.png)

The widgets are still visible.

## What I've tried

- moving the buttons outside of the textfields
- manually unfocusing the text field after the button tap.
- increasing the PumpAndSettle Duration
- using different types of finders to retrieve the widgets